# Extending a homomorphism of a ring to an algebraically closed field

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a subring of a ring $B$.
Suppose $B$ is integral over $A$.
Let $\Omega$ be an algebraically closed field.
Then every homomorphism $\psi\colon A \rightarrow \Omega$ can be extended to a homomorphism 
$\phi\colon B \rightarrow \Omega$?

Comment: The question is not a duplicate.
The question is about homomorphism extensions over integral ring extensions, not over finite ring extensions. A finite ring extension is an integral ring extension, but the converse is not necessarily true.

Comment: The inessential aspect of finiteness (for integral ring extensions) is noted by *both* answers to the proposed duplicate.  I can see no benefit to reopening the Question since it is well answered there (and the Question here has additional answers already).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We know that $\mathfrak{p} = \ker \psi$ is a prime ideal of $A$ since the image of $\psi$ is an subring of $\Omega$, in particular an integral domain. The lying-over theorem implies that there exists a prime ideal $\mathfrak{q}$ of $B$ lying over $\mathfrak{p}$ since $B$ is integral over $A$.
Now consider the compositum $ A \to B \to B/\mathfrak{q}$. The kernel of this compositum is precisely $\mathfrak{p}$ and so we have an injective homomorphism

$$f : A/\mathfrak{p} \to B/\mathfrak{q}$$

such that $B/\mathfrak{q}$ is integral over $A/\mathfrak{p}$. Taking fraction fields, we have that $\textrm{Frac}(B/\mathfrak{q})$ is an algebraic extension of $\textrm{Frac}(A/\mathfrak{p})$. The following steps will now complete the problem:

1. The universal property of quotients gives us a unique ring homomorphism $\overline{\psi} : A/\mathfrak{p} \to \Omega$ that is injective.
2. The universal property of the fraction field now gives a unique ring homomorphism $\Psi: \textrm{Frac}(A/\mathfrak{p} ) \to \Omega$ that extends $\psi$.
3. Use Theorem 1. of Keith Conrad's notes [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/zorn2.pdf) to give us a homomorphism $\Phi : \textrm{Frac}(B/\mathfrak{q}) \to \Omega$.
4. The desired homomorphism from $B$ to $\Omega$ is obtained by doing $$B \to B/\mathfrak{q} \to \textrm{Frac}(B/\mathfrak{q}) \stackrel{\Phi}{\longrightarrow} \Omega. $$

We can put this all in two diagrams:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

As a complement to BenjaLim's perfect answer, let me give an example of an integral extension $A\subset B$ and  of a morphism $\psi:A\to \Omega$ with infinitely many extensions $B\to \Omega$ .

Take $A=\mathbb F_p$ and fix an algebraic closure $B=\Omega=\bar {\mathbb F_p}$ of $\mathbb F_p$.
The inclusion $\psi: \mathbb F_p\to \Omega$ extends to $\phi: B=\Omega\to \Omega:x\to x^p$, the Frobenius automorphism .
But there are many other extensions, the simplest being the infinitely many powers of that Frobenius automorphism, namely the $\phi^n: B=\Omega\to \Omega:x\to x^{p^n}$ where $n\in \mathbb Z$ is arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Using Zorn's lemma, there is a maximal ring $M\subset B$ to which $\psi$ can be extended. Assume $b\in B\setminus M$. What can you conclude?